# How would my database relationship look like. Flask sqlalchemy

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I want to have a User who can rate different movies. A movie can have many ratings; a user can rate many movies.

I thought it would look like this:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=True, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=True)



   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(User, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class Movie(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'movies'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=True)
    release_year = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=True)
    imdb_url = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=True)
    poster = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=True)
    genre = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=True)
    rating = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=True)


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Movie, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class Rating(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'ratings'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    movie_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('movies.id'))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    rating = db.Column(db.Float(), default='0')

    user = db.relationship("User", backref=backref("ratings", order_by=id))
    movie = db.relationship("Movie", backref=backref("ratings", order_by=id))
```

If that is right, how would I query these tables to get all users and their ratings on each movie and then generate a pandas dataframe where the userIds of all users are the columns and all movieIds are the rows and the respective rating is the value?

```
  UserId 1  2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  
 MovieId                                                                                    

   1    5.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 
   2    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 5.0 
   3    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 4.5 0.0 
   4    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 
   5    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

If a user doesn't have rated a movie I still want them in the matrix, like user number 8, who hasn't rated a single movie.

Comment: I can generate the matrix above, but only with users who have rated at least 1 movie and movies who has been rated at least once, with these 2 lines:
     df1 = pd.read_sql(session.query(Rating).statement,session.bind) 
     print(df1.pivot(column='movie_id', index='user_id', values='rating')) 

 But I would like to get all users and all movies, no matter how many times they have rated or been rated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, that's a lot of questions! Let's do one thing at a time.

So, you want Users and Movies. Cool Cool.

Here's how I would define the models:

```
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash
from . import db  # grab sqlalchemy

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(), unique=True)  # Can something be nullable and unique? I think it can be, or that this would be allowed, but still, probably want this to be not null
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))  # Likewise, make password HASH not nullable. Don't store plaintext passwords, seriously.

    @property
    def password(self):
        raise (AttributeError('"password" is not a readable attribute'))

    @password.setter
    def password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def verify_password(self, password):
        return (check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password))

    movies = db.relationship('Movie', secondary='ratings')  # n:m relationship


class Movie(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'movies'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # ...
    users = db.relationship('User', secondary='ratings')  # n:m relationship
    # ...


class Rating():
    __tablename__ = 'ratings'
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
    movie_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('movies.id'), primary_key=True)
    # The following defines a User.ratings attribute that points to this object
    # The backref loads the object dynamically, but accessing the link object directly joins both the user and movie
    user = db.relationship(User, backref=db.backref("ratings", lazy='dynamic'), lazy='joined')
    # Likewise for Movies
    movie = db.relationship(Movie, backref=db.backref("ratings", lazy='dynamic'), lazy='joined')
    # Store User rating information here, as a part of link:
    rating = db.Column(db.Float, default='0')  # Could be nullable, or default could be something impossible like "-1" to distinguish, if needed.
```

Alright, cool... so now you can do stuff like this:

```
user = current_user or User.query.filter_by(id=3087).first()
Rating.query.filter(Rating.user == user).all()  # all ratings by a user (current user or user id = 3087, in this case)
# Same as:
user.ratings  # All ratings by a user

User.query.filter_by(id=user.id).first().ratings  # list of all ratings for a user

great_movie = Movie.query.filter_by(name="Birdemic: Shock and Terror").first()
Movie.query.filter_by(id=great_movie.id).first().ratings  # all ratings for a movie (Birdemic: Shock and Terror, in this case)
# Same as:
great_movie.ratings
```

You can define your matrix method as a view, or maybe even create submatrices for users and movies by placing your matrix generation code as a static method for your model classes:

So, like, you could code the behavior to be:

```
<User Object>.ratings_matrix()
```

Examples (pseudocode only):

```
@app.route('/matrix', methods=['GET'])
def matrix():
    # define pandas matrix, and iteratively fill it with ratings:
    matrix = Matrix() # ?? Idk

    for user in User.query.all():
        for movie in Movie.query.all():
            rating = Rating.query.filter_by(user_id=user.id, movie_id=movie.id).first().rating  # find by ids, then get actual rating value (Rating.rating)

            if rating:
                # add rating to matrix at correct position (user.id, movie.id)
                matrix[user.id, movie.id] = rating
            else:
                matrix[user.id, movie.id] = 0

    return(render_template('ratings_matrix.html', matrix=matrix))  # implies 'templates/ratings_matrix.html'
```

Or like, you could have the matrix pre-created, stored (pickled maybe?) and then retrieved from the db or cache whole. Up to you really!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really helped! :)